# prevent permission modified files from being modified on git

Tags: git, permissions, bitbucket

I have changed a file's permission on a local branch to be **rw-r--r--** but it's still can be modified after pushed to cloud, is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: If only the owner has write access, git must run under the same user as the file is owned by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you mean:

- You want to make a file writable only by you, the owner
- You want to push these files with permissions in tact to a remote (e.g. Bitbucket Cloud or GitHub)
- You want other users who *clone* the repo to be prevented from making changes to these files, because you originally set them to be editable only by the file owner, which was originally you.

There are two problems here.

1. Git doesn't preserve all the permissions changes you set. It only recognises whether you've made a particular file executable. In a git repository, files commonly have only one of the following sets of permissions: `644` (owner can read + write; group/everyone can read only) or `755` (owner can read, write and execute; group/everyone can read & execute only). You can't impose further permissions limitations as git simply won't store them or push them to the remote git host
2. When I as a user clone a repository, all the files are created by my local user account, and now *I* am the owner of those files. Even if these permissions were tracked by git, it *still* wouldn't work, because whomever has cloned the repo owns the local copies of those files.

It sounds to me like what you really want to do is prevent a user from changing certain files in the remote repository. Depending on the repository host, you should be able to implement some kind of git pre-receive hook to reject pushes. Find out more about what your git hosting service can support here and you should be able to implement something that solves this problem.

Comment: Thanks daveruinseverything, your answer is very helpful ... ^_^